# How does the kernel know which drivers belong to which peripherals?

Tags: c, windows, unix, kernel

When the Kernel needs to send output to a certain peripheral, how does it know which driver to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual way is for each driver when first loaded, typically at boot time, to poll the buses it supports and look for matches between what it is designed to support and the returned signatures (vendor and device IDs), and their classes.

This is at least the way it works for the so-called plug and play peripherals.